# What is a more functional way of iteratively summing a list of values while capturing each intermediate result?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, syntax, functional-programming, pure-function

The code below works as expected, but the map lambda is impure.  How could I refactor this to make it pure.  (No need to stick to calling map, we could reduce or whatever else here, I just want it to be pure)

```kotlin
    val entries = listOf(
        Pair(LocalDate.now().minusDays(2), 1), 
        Pair(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1), 2), 
        Pair(LocalDate.now().minusDays(0), 3) 
    )

    private fun buildSumSchedule(entries: List<Pair<LocalDate, Double>>): Map<LocalDate, Double> {
        var runningSum = 0.0
        return entries.sortedBy { it.first }.map {
            runningSum += it.second
            it.copy(second = runningSum)
        }.toMap()
    }

    val sumSchedule = buildSumSchedule(entries)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want here is `scanReduce` that's how you can use the previous item after sorting

```
@ExperimentalStdlibApi
private fun buildSumSchedule(entries: List<Pair<LocalDate, Double>>): Map<LocalDate, Double> =
    entries.sortedBy { it.first }.scanReduce { pair, acc ->
        acc.copy(second = pair.second + acc.second)
    }.toMap()
```

and from kotlin **1.4.0** `runningReduce`

```
private fun buildSumSchedule(entries: List<Pair<LocalDate, Double>>): Map<LocalDate, Double> =
    entries.sortedBy { it.first }.runningReduce{acc, pair ->
        acc.copy(second = pair.second + acc.second)
    }.toMap()
```

Comment: it looks like `scanReduce` has been deprecated in favour of `runningReduce`

Comment: Ooh I’m glad they improved the name of that function before release!